Bash: Preserve argument quotes but cater for none?
In a bash script I take arguments as an array, passing them through to another program, and use them like so:
SOME_ARGS=( "$@" )

# ...

program "${SOME_ARGS[@]}"

This nicely preserves quotes, but unfortunately in this case program rejects an empty argument, so if I don't pass anything it tries to essentially run program "", which errors. Something like program "${SOME_ARGS[@]:---}" to add -- isn't an option as, unfortunately, program doesn't recognise -- to terminate argument parsing.
Is there any better option than seeing if it's empty? In reality the command has a few arguments before SOME_ARGS so I'd rather not repeat them, but that seems like the only real option here.

it tries to essentially run program "" No it does not ! "${SOME_ARGS[@]}" expands to nothing, no argument when the SOME_ARGS array is empty.

I could verify, what Léa Gris is saying, using bash 5.2.15. If you have an old bash version, the behaviour could be different, but a doubt so. Show as a screenshot, which proves your point, and make sure that we can see your bash version, and turn on tracing (set -x).

It's not clear what you want to happen when no arguments are passed to your script. Please create and post a [mcve] (text, not a screenshot, so we can copy/paste it to test with) demonstrating what you're trying to do so we can help you.


Something like program "${SOME_ARGS[@]:---}"

It does not work this way.
Here is demonstration:
cat example.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

program() {
  if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    printf 'program got passed %d arguments\n' "$#"
    printf '\nHere they are:\n'
    printf '%q\n' "$@"
  else
    printf 'program called without argument\n'
  fi
}

# Copy arguments to array
some_args=( "$@" )

program "${some_args[@]}"

Testing:
$ bash test.sh
program called without argument

$ bash test.sh foo 'bar baz' quux
program got passed 3 arguments

Here they are:
foo
bar\ baz
quux



This nicely preserves quotes,

Not exactly.  The shell still performs quote removal on the command you type, but your approach preserves the effect your quoting had on how the command line was split into words.

but unfortunately in this case program rejects an empty argument, so if I don't pass anything it tries to essentially run program ""

Simply, no.  "$@" expands to nothing when there are no arguments, in which case SOME_ARGS=( "$@" ) initializes the value of SOME_ARGS as an empty array.  Likewise, "${SOME_ARGS[@]}" expands to nothing when SOME_ARGS refers to an empty array.  These forms are exactly the way to capture command-line arguments and pass them on to another command verbatim.  They work correctly for that purpose with any number of arguments, including 0, as Léa demonstrates in more detail.
If you're getting a zero-length command-line argument presented to program then that is not the fault of the code presented.  It may be that such an argument is present on the script command line, or it may be that something else in the script that you have not disclosed is responsible for it.  Or perhaps you've mischaracterized the problem altogether.

Is there any better option than seeing if it's empty?


If you want something that expands to nothing at all, not even an empty string, when no command-line arguments are passed to the script then you've already got it.

If you want to determine the number of elements in SOME_ARGS then use ${#SOME_ARGS[@]}.

If you want to scan SOME_ARGS for empty elements, or to filter them out, then consider using something along these lines:
some_filtered_args=()
for arg in "${SOME_ARGS[@]}"; do
  test -n "$arg" && some_filtered_args+=("$arg")
done

# now use some_filtered_args


If you want to avoid empty arguments in the first place then fix whatever is producing them. That is not part of the code presented in the question.



In reality the command has a few arguments before SOME_ARGS so I'd rather not repeat them, but that seems like the only real option here.

Not at all.  If you have an additional set of options that you want to pass, then you can put them in a separate array, whose elements you can expand into whatever command you like.  This will allow you to set them at an appropriate time and in an appropriate place, and not repeat them.  If they always come immediately after the command name then you can even put the command name itself into the array:
base_command=(program -m xyzzy)

# ...

# Execute command:
"${base_command[@]}" "${some_filtered_args[@]}"

